# EF insert multiple related tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to save data into a database from a C# app using Linq/Entity Framework. Inserting to a single table is simple enough, but I'm not sure how to insert data into three tables which are all interconnected with auto-increment identities?
This is for a scrape, so I'm taking a thread and all it's posts - each **ThreadTitle** and each **Post** is associated with a **User** (not actual table names).

My design idea was to scrape a full thread into memory and then do a "batch" insert. To reduce load, I was hoping there is some way to maintain the relationship constraints, without doing look-ups, multiple inserts etc.

Comment: Are you using code-first, or database-first?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking... I have my DB setup with the PK/FK constraints in place, and I'd like to scrape all data into memory and then make infrequent inserts to the DB

Comment: Database-first is when you use EF to create an Entity Data Model from an existing database. With code-first, you design your classes first and then use EF to generate database based on these classes.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, so then I'm doing this Database-first.

Comment: You can try this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/06/friction-less-object-graph-n-tier-using.html

Comment: I think you can also try EF's STE for saving your object graph, saving is very streamlined, only the newly added, updated and deleted are sent across the wire. I'm not keen to try it though, it feels like ADO.NET all over again :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save two records which are related because there is a FK in one (A) to the other one (B), do the following:

- Create object B
- Add object B to context
- Create object A
- Set the navigation property in A which points to B (A.B) to value B.
- Add object A to context
- Save changes in context

You don't actually have to add both objects to the context, one is enough, since there are related EF can find everything 'in the tree'.
EF will figure out by itself what to insert first and set the correct id's.

Is this what you mean? Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is what I'm curious about... if the EF works in such a way that as long as I create the objects in EF, then they will save to the DB and maintain their correct associations (e.g. correct user associated with a thread creation, and a post, and posts under the correct threads - all as PK-FK relationships).

Comment: It will work as long as the context knows about them. New object? Save it. Existing object which you loaded with the context? Nothing extra to do. Existing object which you loaded with another context? Attach it.