# Adding several related entities before calling savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

If your adding several related entities at once, should you call SaveChanges after each, or can it be done once?  Im getting an error such as "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint".

Orders has a navigation property to an entity Records.
I want to add Records to an order, then call savechanges.
When I do, I get an error complaining about the primary key on Records.

I want to do something like this

```
Order o = new Order{.......}
Record r1 = new Record{...}
Record r2 = new Record{....}
o.Records.Add(r1)
o.Records.Add(r2)
Context.Orders.Add(o);
Context.SaveChanges()
```

Isnt this the right approach?

...
[image: Schema]

```
        //populate order entity
        Order o = new Order { AccountKey = iAccnt, OfficeKey = iOffice, UserKey = iUser, CreatedDate = dtCreateDate };

        //save            
        ctx.Orders.Add(o);

        //locations
        Location origin = new Location
        {
            Order = o,
            LocationTypeKey = ctx.LocationTypes.Where(a => a.TypeName == "Origin").First().LocationTypeId,               
            Address1 = " test address 1",
            Address2 = " test Address 2",
            City = oi.OriginCity,
            StateKey = ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.OriginState).First().StateId,
            CountryKey = ctx.Countries.Where(a => a.CountryName == oi.OriginCountry).First().CountryId
        };

        Location destn = new Location
        {
            Order = o,
            LocationTypeKey = ctx.LocationTypes.Where(a => a.TypeName == "Destination").First().LocationTypeId,
            Address1 = " test address 1",
            Address2 = " test Address 2",
            City = oi.OriginCity,
            StateKey = ctx.States.Where(a => a.StateName == oi.DestinationState).First().StateId,
            CountryKey = ctx.Countries.Where(a => a.CountryName == oi.DestinationCountry).First().CountryId
        };





        try
        {
            int rows = ctx.SaveChanges();
            if (rows == 0)
            {
                retval = false;
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException  ex)
        {
            string exst = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: that should work fine.  What do your primary keys look like?

Comment: Is the PK error on Order or Record? What is the Order PK and the Record PK?

Comment: Please paste your Record and Order classes

Comment: Dont have the code with me at the moment, but the Record is where I got the PK error.  There is no FK in Order, but Record has FK to Order.  In other words, Record has references back to Order.  There Record to Order is many to one.  The idea is that there can be lots of Records that point back to a single order, or a single order can have lots of Records.  Ill paste the code in the morning.

Comment: I think I need to reverse the order in which Im adding the "related" entities.  This link helped http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee828425(v=vs.100).aspx  So, in my case, after creating an order, I add that in with the creation of each new Record entity.  Trying it this way, Im no longer getting a PK error and although the order is added, but the recods are not.

Comment: This indicates that the association between Order and Record is not well defined. Please show the classes and the mappings.

Comment: Code updated (see post above).  Again, just to update at this point, the Order entity is created, but the Location(s) are not.

Comment: This post by Maarten seems to help , regarding the general sequence of adding related entities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477852/ef-insert-multiple-related-tables.  I think I need to possibly add each Location to the context before calling saving changes?  However, when I do that I get PK violation on the Location entity.

Comment: IT WORKED....my problem was my Location table...stupid and simple.  Just had not set the Location PK as an identity.  Once I did that, the  clouds parted and the sun came down.  All was well.

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPQlXNH36mI